# Combine two data frames by one variable and combining columns under one main header

Tags: r, tabular

I want to combine two dataframes T2 and T4 by variable "Industry" and the columns of each data set with one main heading.    So in the final output table I want columns Industry, three columns of T2 under one column heading "Executive" and three other columns of T4 as sub-columns of one heading "management".

```
T2
                         Industry percentage_Yes percentage_No Total_responses
    1                         ALL           94 %           6 %             117
    2  Banking/Financial Services           83 %          17 %               6
    3                   Chemicals          100 %           0 %               5
    4              Consumer Goods           75 %          25 %               8
    5                      Energy           89 %          11 %               9
    6                   High Tech          100 %           0 %               8
    7       Insurance/Reinsurance          100 %           0 %              14
    8               Life Sciences          100 %           0 %              11
    9                   Logistics             --            --               3
    10            Mining & Metals             --            --               1
    11        Other Manufacturing          100 %           0 %              11
    12    Other Non-Manufacturing             --            --               3
    13         Retail & Wholesale          100 %           0 %              12
    14   Services (Non-Financial)           88 %          12 %              24
    15   Transportation Equipment             --            --               2
    16                       <NA>             --            --               0

T4
                     Industry percentage_Yes percentage_No Total_responses
1                         ALL           96 %           4 %             121
2  Banking/Financial Services           86 %          14 %               7
3                   Chemicals          100 %           0 %               5
4              Consumer Goods          100 %           0 %               8
5                      Energy          100 %           0 %               9
6                   High Tech          100 %           0 %               9
7       Insurance/Reinsurance           93 %           7 %              15
8               Life Sciences           91 %           9 %              11
9                   Logistics             --            --               3
10            Mining & Metals             --            --               1
11        Other Manufacturing          100 %           0 %              12
12    Other Non-Manufacturing             --            --               3
13         Retail & Wholesale          100 %           0 %              12
14   Services (Non-Financial)           92 %           8 %              24
15   Transportation Equipment             --            --               2
16                       <NA>             --            --               0

> dput(T2)
structure(list(Industry = c("ALL", "Banking/Financial Services", 
"Chemicals", "Consumer Goods", "Energy", "High Tech", "Insurance/Reinsurance", 
"Life Sciences", "Logistics", "Mining & Metals", "Other Manufacturing", 
"Other Non-Manufacturing", "Retail & Wholesale", "Services (Non-Financial)", 
"Transportation Equipment", NA), percentage_Yes = c("94 %", "83 %", 
"100 %", "75 %", "89 %", "100 %", "100 %", "100 %", "--", "--", 
"100 %", "--", "100 %", "88 %", "--", "--"), percentage_No = c("6 %", 
"17 %", "0 %", "25 %", "11 %", "0 %", "0 %", "0 %", "--", "--", 
"0 %", "--", "0 %", "12 %", "--", "--"), Total_responses = c(117, 
6, 5, 8, 9, 8, 14, 11, 3, 1, 11, 3, 12, 24, 2, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), .Names = c("Industry", "percentage_Yes", "percentage_No", 
"Total_responses"))
> dput(T4)
structure(list(Industry = c("ALL", "Banking/Financial Services", 
"Chemicals", "Consumer Goods", "Energy", "High Tech", "Insurance/Reinsurance", 
"Life Sciences", "Logistics", "Mining & Metals", "Other Manufacturing", 
"Other Non-Manufacturing", "Retail & Wholesale", "Services (Non-Financial)", 
"Transportation Equipment", NA), percentage_Yes = c("96 %", "86 %", 
"100 %", "100 %", "100 %", "100 %", "93 %", "91 %", "--", "--", 
"100 %", "--", "100 %", "92 %", "--", "--"), percentage_No = c("4 %", 
"14 %", "0 %", "0 %", "0 %", "0 %", "7 %", "9 %", "--", "--", 
"0 %", "--", "0 %", "8 %", "--", "--"), Total_responses = c(121, 
7, 5, 8, 9, 9, 15, 11, 3, 1, 12, 3, 12, 24, 2, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), .Names = c("Industry", "percentage_Yes", "percentage_No", 
"Total_responses"))
```

I have tried tabular but then m getting Industry column 2 times:

```
library("tables")
st<-rbind(data.frame(T2, Employee_Level = 'Exe', what = factor(rownames(T2), levels = rownames(T2)), 
             row.names= NULL, check.names = FALSE), 
  data.frame(T4,Employee_Level = 'Mgmt',what = factor(rownames(T4), levels = rownames(T4)), 
             row.names = NULL,check.names = FALSE))

mytable <- tabular(Heading()*what ~ Employee_Level*(`Industry`+`percentage_Yes`+`percentage_No`+`Total_responses`)*Heading()*(identity),data=st)
latex(mytable)
```

Comment: `merge(T2,T4, by = "Industry")` and renaming your columns ?

Comment: Yes, merge will work but I want to add another header on the top of the table , columns of these two tables should be subcolumns to 2 main headers

Comment: `merge(T2,T4, by = "Industry",suffixes = c("_T2","_T4")) ` . It adds _T2 for the  columns in T2 and _T4 for the T4 columns

Comment: Yes, but I don't want it as suffix. I am doing something wrong with tabular function. If that is corrected it will be done

Comment: I'd rather leave the data as is and use the `xtable` package to tweak the output into the latex form you want.

Comment: @LAP Hi, would be great if you can please elaborate how we can do it with xtable

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using (my) huxtable package:

```
library(huxtable)
my_data      <- cbind(T2, T4)[, c(1:4, 6:8)]
my_hux       <- as_hux(my_data, add_colnames = TRUE)
my_hux       <- insert_row(my_hux, rep("", 7))
my_hux[1, 2] <- "Executive"
my_hux[1, 5] <- "Management"
colspan(my_hux)[1, 2] <- 3
colspan(my_hux)[1, 5] <- 3
my_hux[2, 2:7] <- rep(c("% yes", "% no", "Total responses"), 2)
number_format(my_hux) <- 0

# This should look like what you want:
my_hux
```